# How to Upload last version to branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

Hello I am trying to learn how to use github but could not find an answer to my question. I have a project on my project_edits branch. After I formatted my pc I created a folder an cloned my project that is on project_edits branch to that folder. I deleted that version and copied there my project's last version from my computer. Now I want to upload the last version to project_edits branch on github, not to master. In my terminal it seems I am at master branch on local. Should I create a project_edits branch also in local? How can I push my project to project_edits branch on remote. Thank you for any help ...

Comment: Do you have that branch currently checked out locally? Have you tried `git push origin project_edits`?

Comment: Yes I did.error: src refspec version2 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.................................

Comment: Haven't seen that before, but according to your error below, you have to pull the latest changes from the remote branch, merge the changes, then you can commit and push back to the remote

Comment: Mm... Could you be more specific? So far I get that you cloned a project into your computer, after that, you removed that project you just cloned and placed your new files? Now you want to push them back? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

To push from your local `master` branch to the `project_edits` branch on the remote you can try:

```
git push origin master:project_edits
```

Comment: $ git push origin master:project_edits
To https://github.com/.........................................
 ! [rejected]        master -> project_edits(non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...........................
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: How did you end up on the `master` branch?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You're in a big mess right now, and I'm trying to bring out information so that we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. git branch (which branch)
2. git status (it's in red has modification in local not remote, but green is added but not pushed, and if pushed will show you nothing to do")
3. git add . (added because you will pushed in an commit) or git add name_archive
4. git commit -m "Any message in this commit"
5. git push -u origin name_branch (name_branch master,develop,etc).